# POST AJAX javascript SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I already have code AJAX post method, I consume the web service from java, but my code in AJAX is success but not updated.

```
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {"nomorDosir": "01041701288", "kodeCabang": "A02"},
          processData: false,
          success: function(data){
              console.log("success"+data);
          },
          error: function(e){
              console.log("error: "+e);
          }
        });
```

When I see the log console, show from console success, not error, but not updated the data.

How to fix this problem? and one question, Where the wrong place? in java (API webservice) or in javascript?

Thanks.
Bobby

Comment: Did you check your `Network` tab and ensured that the call has returned any data? (with 200 http status code)

Comment: Where is the data not updated ? In the parameter of success callback or the data is received from service but UI is not updated with new data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about encoding data. You must encode data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded and then send to the server. [$.param(data)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) is a jQuery function to encode data. So change your code as following:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: $.param({"nomorDosir": "01041701288", "kodeCabang": "A02"}),
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      success: function(data){
          console.log("success"+data);
      },
      error: function(e){
          console.log("error: "+e);
      }
    });
```